# Populating a Select Element with .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, select, each

I am getting back a huge crazy JSON from an API, and I am struggling with putting it inside a select box. So far I have this code:

```
$('#gaua').live('change', function () {

        var dropDownValue = $(this).val();

        $("#gaCell").html("<select>");

        $.each(gaAccount, function(k, v) {
            $.each(v, function(k1, v1) {
                console.log("k1 "+k1+" "+dropDownValue);
                if(k1 == dropDownValue) {
                    console.log("k1 is equal to dropDownValue");
                    $.each(v1, function(k2, v2) {
                        console.log("v1 "+v1+" k2 "+k2+" v2 "+v2);
                        $("#gaCell").append("<option value='"+v2+"'>"+k2+"</option>");
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        $("#gaCell").append("</select>");

        console.log($("#gaCell").html());

    });
```

When I look at the console I see this:

```
<select></select><option value="4434">Option 1</option><option value="43333380">Option 2</option><option value="3233223">Option 3</option> ...
```

Why is the `<select></select>` being appended initially? Should the opening tag be set, then the option values added and finally the closed select tag?

The code looks crap, but I need to get this working properly before I clean it up. Any advice would really help, thanks!

Comment: Why are you calling live for a change event? The change event doesn't bubble up in IE...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I used live because this drop down is added after the page has loaded and the user takes an action. I guess I do that out of habit when something gets added after the DOM has loaded. Is it not necessary?

Comment: The problem is that live depends on events bubbling and change doesn't bubble in IE. Try it in IE, I think it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, so how does one go attaching a change listener to an added element in IE?

Comment: If you are dynamically adding elements that you need to listen for their change event, you need to add the handler everytime you create it, and you need to remove it before you destroy it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to construct your element first, before appending it.

When you call `$('#gaCell').html('<select>')`, you're telling jQuery to append a select element, including closing tag.

Try this:

```
    $('#gaua').live('change', function () {

        var dropDownValue = $(this).val();

        $select = $("<select>");

        $.each(gaAccount, function(k, v) {
            $.each(v, function(k1, v1) {
                console.log("k1 "+k1+" "+dropDownValue);
                if(k1 == dropDownValue) {
                    console.log("k1 is equal to dropDownValue");
                    $.each(v1, function(k2, v2) {
                        console.log("v1 "+v1+" k2 "+k2+" v2 "+v2);
                        $select.append("<option value='"+v2+"'>"+k2+"</option>");
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        $("#gaCell").append($select);

        console.log($("#gaCell").html());

    });
```

This way you build up the full select element including children before appending it.

Comment: Very interesting thank you for the answer. I'm curious when I append the closing select tag at the end why don't I see that in my console when I log the entire contents of the element? For example `<select></select><option ..... </option></select>`

Comment: Because you can't append just a closing tag. When you call `append()`, jQuery is going to try to parse the string you pass as valid html. And a single closing tag isn't valid, so it silently ignores it and does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't append half a tag to an element, so when you try to put `"<select>"` in the cell, the browser will make a complete select element out of it.

Create the select element first:

```
var sel = $('<select/>');
```

Now you can add options to it:

```
sel.append($('<option/>', { value: v2 }).text(k2));
```

After the loop you add the select element to the cell:

```
$('#gaCell').append(sel);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think string juggling for building HTML is somewhat unelegant. Consider this:

```
$('#gaua').live('change', function () {
    var dropDownValue = $(this).val();
    var $select = $("<select>").appendTo("#gaCell");

    $.each(gaAccount, function(i, acc) {
        $.each(acc, function(name, details) {
            if(name == dropDownValue) {
                $.each(details, function(label, value) {
                    $select.append("<option>", {value: value, text: label});
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also, I recommend using variable names that have a meaning istead of `k1` and `v1` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#gaCell").html("<select>");`  will make the contents of `#gaCell` = `'<select></select>'`;

`$("#gaCell").append("</select>");` will add `'<select></select>'` to the end of whatever else is inside `#gaCell`

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the options, you have to insert into the select, not into #gaCell. I would generate the HTML in a string and then call `$("#gaCell").html(someHTML)` instead of multiple DOM insertions, it's a little faster;

```
   var html = "<select>";

    $.each(gaAccount, function(k, v) {
        $.each(v, function(k1, v1) {
            if(k1 == dropDownValue) {
                $.each(v1, function(k2, v2) {
                    html += "<option value='"+v2+"'>"+k2+"</option>";
                });
            }
        });
    });        
    html += "</select>";
    $("#gaCell").html(html);
```

A hint for postiong code, remove your console.logs, just adds noise.